# How to calculate its radius and its angle?

Tags: geometry

[image: this is the illustration]

I am really sorry if this question is too easy for you. but i am not able to find the answer. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

The two equations for $r$ and $\theta$ are
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}r\theta=7.85,\\
(r-1.5)\theta=4.39.\end{array}\right.$$

Therefore, $\theta=\frac{7.85-4.39}{1.5}=2.307$ rad is the angle, and then $\,r=\frac{7.85}{\theta}=3.403$ is the radius of the outer arc as drawn in the figure.

Comment: I think we three together have totally solved the question... :)

Comment: @painday, Yeah. It's really like finding the slope and intercept of a straight line. But the geometry looks so different.

Comment: Thank you for helping and solving, to both of you :)

Comment: @Arthur, thanks. I've made that clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the two radii are $r_1 < r_2$

The two arc lengths (given) are $s_1 = r_1\theta$ and $s_2 = r_2\theta$

The difference between these arcs are $s_2 - s_1 = (r_2-r_1)\theta$, where the difference between the two radii is also given.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes I can...Thanks  :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Denote the angle as $\theta,$ and the large radius as $R,$ then we have

$\left\{\begin{aligned}&R\cdot\theta=7.85,\\ &(R-1.5)\cdot \theta=4.39.\end{aligned}\right.$